# PHP: File upload move_uploaded_file() not working

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I just made a file upload code and I was wondering why the file upload wasn't working. I changed the upload dir to 0777. This is my upload HTML code:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And PHP Code:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
echo "Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
echo "Uploaded file: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kilobytes<br />";

if (file_exists("/files/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. No joke-- this error is almost <i><b>impossible</b></i> to get. Try again, I bet 1 million dollars it won't ever happen again.";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/filebro/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Done";
  }
}
?>
```

So, what could the problem possibly be?

Comment: Please define "not working". Do you get any error messages? Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Do you mean to be using your paths as actually root paths on the server, or are those supposed to be relative to your web root?

Comment: you should be aware that someone could upload .htaccess files and do lots of fun things with this

Comment: I do have error reporting on, but I get nothing. No errors.

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"filebro/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
if (file_exists("/files/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
```

will always return false. The file is saved with its temp name.

Try

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]))
```

instead.