# File upload / move temp not working on nginx

Tags: php, file-upload, nginx

So, i've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952329/php-file-upload-move-uploaded-file-not-working) about move_uploaded_file() problems. However, on my apache-powered localhost lamp stack, its working just fine. So i think it may be a filesystem / path thing, and not a code thing.

when uploading files to my site locally, it works.

but when I'm on the QA server (which is nginx powered), i get this error:

```
2012/09/08 15:34:21 [error] 11794#0: *5187 FastCGI sent in stderr: "files not empty
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/var/www/qa.mysite.com/mysite/app/files/maps-aprilfools.tiff): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/qa.mysite.com/mysite/app/models/files.php on line 516
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpvdtznP' to '/var/www/qa.mysite.com/mysite/app/files/maps-aprilfools.tiff' in /var/www/qa.mysite.com/mysite/app/models/files.php on line 516" while reading response header from upstream, client: 72.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: qa.mysite.com, request: "POST /projects/3/files HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "qa.mysite.com", referrer: "http://qa.mysite.com/projects/3/files"
```

and this is the code that I wrote to handle uploading a file:

```
public function fileUploadToProject( $project_id ) {
    if ($_FILES["upload-file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    } else {

        $dbSuccess      = false;

        $tmp_name       = $_FILES["upload-file"]["tmp_name"];
        $name           = $_FILES["upload-file"]["name"]; // someFile.ext
        $size           = $_FILES['upload-file']['size']; //size in bytes
        $mime           = $_FILES['upload-file']['type']; //size in bytes

        $destination    = __FILES__.'/'.$name;
        $uploaded       = move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $destination );

        // add entry to database.

        /*
         * null because there is no container yet.
         * We're only uploading to local
         */
        $user_container_name = null; 

        $uploaded_by = LoggedInUser::get_user_id();

        /*
         * Set this 1 when we're not dealing with our external fileserver
         */
        $isLocal = 1;

        /*
         * Probably shouldn't do this forever for storage size reasons, but for now its useful.
         */
        $localPath = $destination;

        $task_id = null;

        if( $uploaded ) {
        $dbSuccess = $this->insertFileRefService( $task_id, 
                                                  $project_id,
                                                  $user_container_name, 
                                                  $name,
                                                  $mime, 
                                                  $size,
                                                  $uploaded_by,
                                                  $isLocal,
                                                  $localPath
                );
            if($dbSuccess) {
                return true;
            } else {
                // should I rollback / delete that file?
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

So, is there anything I should know about moving temp files to my filesystem with on nginx? or do you think it is simply a path problem? code problem?

Also, please note that line 516 is this: `$uploaded = move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $destination );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The folder had problems with permissions, among other things.**

the `/files` directory in that path actually doesn't exist. I somehow never realized that the folder simply wasn't there. Whoops.

then, i had to determine what user was used by nginx to execute php:

```
ps aux | grep "nginx"
```

then i had to `chown` the `files` directory:

```
chown -R root:userFromStep1 files
```

then i had to `chmod` the directory:

```
chmod g+w files
```

that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Can please try with giving the exact path instead of using the `__FILES__`. Because it'll not be nginx problem. it will be path problem only