# php upload image with form not working

Tags: php, html, image, forms, upload

I tried a lot suggestions at other people's threats about the same problem, but they didn't work. 
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Part of my form:

```
<form id="register-Form" name="register-Form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"     action="exec.php">

<div class="register-line">
   <div class="ricon"><i class="fa fa-male"></i> </div> 
    picture
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" class="register-text">  </input>
</div>
```

exec.php code

```
$target_path = "/images/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 //succes
} else{
//nothing
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the error?

Comment: On a sidenote, inputs don't have an ending tag, they are either closed this way <input type="text" /> or <input type="text">(No ending tags here)

Comment: what is your php error or error_log ?

Comment: Also, maybe the '/' before images may be the problem in case in target_path. Looks like the same error as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952329/php-file-upload-move-uploaded-file-not-working

Comment: To clarify: I didn't get an error (also hadn't really coded error catching and stuff yet) but I got it thanks to you guys.

Comment: @MHakvoort Indeed. Where an answer given there and here, both don't explain why it wasn't working and just saying "Try this". Who's going to "learn" anything if nobody points out the errors in given "answers", as opposed to some comments where they speak of "path" issues ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey you :) You are right. But in fact, I didn't really know how I fixed it at the time, just copy-pasted the guys answer and it worked (wich ofcourse isn't good because you don't learn it that way). Now that I read this, even Í am thinking "what the hell was my error?"

Comment: The issue was going from `$target_path = "/images/";` to `$target_path = "images/";` without the forward slash in front of `images`. In order to use a forward slash in front of the folder, would require a full server path such as, and for example `$target_path = "/var/user/you/httpdocs/images/";`. Now, you have "learned" something ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code

```
$temp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$image = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$img = "images/".$image;
move_uploaded_file($temp, $img);
echo "<img src=images/".$image' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php include('connect.php');

$uploadDir = '/pictures/';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

$result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
if (!$result) {
echo "Error uploading <strong>file</strong>";
exit;
}

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
}

$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$query = "INSERT INTO ".$user_pictures." (file, title, description) VALUES ('".$filePath."', '".$title."', '".$description."')";

mssql_query($query); 

}

?>
```